# Showing User's personal public page after login instead of Site's public page

Tags: java, liferay, personalization

I am new to liferay.

I created a new user (not `Power-user`) and created personal Public and Private pages, but when I login I see public pages of the site.

How can I make it to display personal Public pages by default?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to redirect the logged in user to a particular page you can look into this
    http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Custom+redirect+after+login

if you want to disable the public pages at all then you can look into this
    http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/90196

If none of these solve your problem please elaborate the question to your specific requirement.